# How to turn off tooltips / suggestions in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have all of these tooltips always showing up when using VSCode, but I don't know what to turn off. I have tried turning off Python Linters and hover tooltips, but I don't seem to be able to turn off the right things. I primarily use the [Kite](https://kite.com/integrations/vs-code/) extension, so I don't need 3 different suggestions popping up all the time. This ends up clogging up my screen as much as Pycharm.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your JSON settings

```
"editor.parameterHints": false,
```

[Source](https://blog.shawnhyde.com/post/2019/02/16/how-to-disable-popup-tips-in-visual-studio-code)